# Overloading operator<< for printing as a member

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

Is there a way to overload the << operator, as a class member, to print values as a text stream. Such as:

```
class TestClass {
public:
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os) {
        return os << "I'm in the class, msg=" << msg << endl;
    }

private:
    string msg;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    TestClass obj = TestClass();
    cout << obj;

    return 0;
}
```

The only way I could think of was to overload the operator outside of the class:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, TestClass& obj) {
    return os << "I'm outside of the class and can't access msg" << endl;
}
```

But then the only way to access the private parts of the object would be to friend the operator function, and I'd rather avoid friends if possible and thus ask you for alternative solutions.

Any comments or recommendations on how to proceed would be helpful :)

Comment: Aren't friends supposed to solve this very problem ? Why would you want to avoid them ?

Comment: The `<<` needs to be nonmember, but it can be a friend.

Comment: Friends are to answer questions, not solve problems!

Comment: `friend`s are your friends. Why do you want to avoid them?

Comment: I recommend reading http://drdobbs.com/184401197 and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.2.

Comment: `friend`s are part of the encapsulation of the class; they're just called using a different syntax.  There's nothing wrong with `friend`s, and no real reason to avoid them.

Comment: @JamesKanze: If you _can_ avoid insight without losing relevant performance, then you should do so, so as to decrease coupling. I.e., if you can implement parts of the interface without private/protected access and without sacrificing too much, you should. On the other hand, if not making it a `friend` means you must tweak the interface, then that's a big enough sacrifice and the `friend` is the lesser evil.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with declaring friends: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/99595/12917

Comment: @phresnel: A function that serializes a class is inherently tightly coupled to that class it streams. Since the streaming is inherently already tightly coupled then making a friend does not increase coupling but rather **documents the coupling**. The alternative is to make the operator<< call a print method (this may seem to decrease the coupling but instead binds the coupling to a different method so you have not decreased coupling just moved it).

Comment: @phresnel I think that's a good summary.  The key idea is that `friend` is good when it increases encapsulation, bad when it decreases it.

Comment: @LokiAstari Never the less, there are often good reasons to go with the `print` method.  (The most obvious is that it can be polymorphic.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: No disagreement there. But when I use print I often (not always) make print private. In this case the stream operator is still a friend (this way I document that the extended interface).

Comment: @LokiAstari: I'm would not say streaming is inherently coupled to the class. Take for example containers: they can be streamed simply by iterating over them and streaming each element successively. No need to know the internals.

Comment: @LucTouraille: Great counter-example. But I would consider containers a separate class (especially since they don't have their own stream operators).

Comment: @James Kanze: Good summary there, exactly my point. My conversation-fu is weak today. I am unsure on the serialization part, though. Is ostream's intention really full serialization, or user friendly output? Floating types e.g. are not trivial to serialize using decimal numbers, as is the default with ostream. I would intuitively think, therefore, that ostream is more for classy user interaction, than for persistence.

Comment: @phresnel: You can serialize a float exactly as hex format string using: (C++03 stream << std::fixed << std::scientific << floatValue (broken in old g++)) (C++11 stream << std::hexfloat << floatValue). See printf("%a")

Comment: @phresnel The `iostream` abstraction is textual input and output, not bitwise serialization.  For other formats, you generally have to roll your own (or possibly find something existing on the net).

Comment: @LokiAstari Something seems wrong there: in `stream << std::fixed << std::scientific`, the manipulator `std::scientific` negates any effect of the `std::fixed`; you output all following floating point values as scientific.  With regards to serialization, you can use text format, provided you use enough digits (which depends on the floating point format---17 is sufficient for IEEE double).

Comment: @James Kanze: That was my point, that streaming operators usually only need the outside view, for a user interface, but not inner information needed for persistence.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Yeah, but the default behaviour is to provide a user interface, not serialization/persistence.

Comment: @phresnel: Are you saying that `{std::ofstream s("plop"); plop << myObject; }{std::ifstream s("plop");s >> mysecondobject;}` will not save and restore your object. Then I would say your object is not designed well. I would expect your input and output operators to be symmetric for any class you define.

Comment: @JamesKanze: See Table X: Floating-point Conversions: `ios_base::fixed | ios_base::scientific conversion %a` (Table number varies per standard but it should be under [facet.num.put.virtuals])

Comment: @LokiAstari That's not present in C++03, so you'd need a very recent compiler for it to work.  More to the point, your code didn't set `floatfield` to `ios_base::fixed | ios_base::scientific`; it set `floatfield` to `ios_base::scientific`.  `std::scientific` uses the two argument form of `ios_base::setf` (and that hasn't changed in C++11).

Comment: @LokiAstari: Not untrue what you say. However, considering how iostreams don't serialize correctly by default, and how hard it is to define performant deserialization for complex types (think pixar and disney here), as well as human readable (only the non-redundant stuff) output, combined in one `operator<</>>` combination, I would _personally_ not consider iostreams for larger-scale serialization. Users of my 3d-quadtree-class might be interested in ostreaming some parameters like depth, but istreaming some function `f(x,z)->y`. I think iostreams really lack a precise definition of their use.

Comment: @phresnel: I'll let the guys at boost serialization team know.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I think we were talking iostreams?

Comment: @phresnel: Were do you think boost serialize actually serializes data?

Comment: @LokiAstari: It depends. Default is the streaming operators, but for more complex types, you write your own serialization function/s which in turn use those. boost::serialization (as well as a serialization framework I developed) uses iostreams, but is not a specialization thereof. I've peeked into the standard, and couldn't find a reference either, except input/output, which is a very manifold term.

Comment: @phresnel: It uses a **stream**. And the <io **stream** > library define?

Comment: @LokiAstari: a) we lack a clear definition of _stream_, b) if it discovers e.g. a `serialize` member function, that is called, and then it is _your_ turn to tell boost::serialization the fragments of data to be serialized. This process is recursive. As for a) and b): I am not sure what you want to tell me. I use my keyboard, and we have to do with each other, yet I am not my keyboard and my keyboard is not me.

Comment: @phresnel: I like your futile attempt at obfuscation. But I consider the conversation over as you have said nothing of any use yet.

Comment: @Loki Astari: I begin losing track of your discussion structure. Standard says: I/O. Fine. But I/O can be I/O for sake of user interaction, or I/O for sake of persistence. Not fine: Lack of precise definition which I/O is preferred in C++. Boils down to: Not clear if streaming-operators need full insight or not. Counter-Example: Non-friend `operator<<` may work fine for containers for introspection-by-user. Now: Explain why boost-serialization supports your definition of iostreams-serialization.  ... I like your futile attempt at hiding the original discussion... And, which obfuscation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have stumbled across the canonical way to implement this functionality.  What you have is correct.

Comment: This is not correct because it won't compile. In the setup from the question one would have to write something ugly like `obj<<cout;`.

Answer (score 14):

It needs to be a non-member, since the class forms the second argument of the operator, not the first. If the output can be done using only the public interface, then you're done. If it needs access to non-public members, then you'll have to declare it a friend; that's what friends are for.

```
class TestClass {
public:
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, TestClass const & tc) {
        return os << "I'm a friend of the class, msg=" << tc.msg << endl;
    }

private:
    string msg;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution also works for output of other overloaded operators. For eg  `cout<<(s1+s2)` didn't work when using other methods. Any reason why this might be happening?

Comment: For a more exhaustive answer around this topic, see accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516720/where-to-put-overload-code

Answer (score 6):

I believe one popular way to do this is a non-member, non-friend free `operator<<` that calls a public non-virtual `print` method within your class. This print method can either do the work or delegate to a protected virtual implementation.

```
class TestClass {
public:
    ostream& print(ostream& os) const {
        return os << "I'm in the class, msg=" << msg << endl;
    }

private:
    string msg;
};


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, TestClass& obj) {
    return obj.print(os);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    TestClass obj;
    cout << obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I support this solution above using a friend declaration. It maintains encapsulation and gets the job done.

Comment: @broc I don't see any real difference in the encapsulation.  In one case, the author of the class explicitly gives access rights to a single instance of `operator<<()`; in this method, he explicitly gives access rights to a function named `print()`.  Where is the difference?  (There may be other reasons to use the `print()` method, but more or less encapsulation isn't one of them.)

Comment: @JamesKanze You could argue that declaring a member public is just the author giving access rights to everyone explicitly and hence it does not break encapsulation. Whether you buy this or not depends on where you draw the line. I personally think that the line must be drawn as far as possible in the opposite direction; having the print method allows you to distribute the class in a .dll, distribute it without source and still allows the user of the library to write their overloaded operator<< for their convenience. Can you get any more encapsulated? From the perspective...

Comment: @JamesKanze of just the language I can't disagree with you, however, the language is used to create an executable or a library and I think that for the purpose of developing professionally, the concept of encapsulation must reach further than just thinking in terms of the language.

Comment: @broc Declaring a member public loosens encapsulation, since it makes the member part of the public interface.  Declaring a function `friend` makes that function part of the class' public interface; by making a function part of the interface, rather than data, you are actually increasing encapsulation.  Too many functions (or poorly designed functions, like getters and setters) weaken encapsulation too, but in this regard, whether the function is a friend or a member is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it member of the class, that is on the left of `<<`, which is `ostream` in your case.

What you can do, though, is have a base class with `void do_stream(ostream& o);` member for all your streamables and non-member `operator<<` that would call it.

Comment: I don't. I'm just stating the fact that if one wants it to be a class member, the class should be `std::ostream`. Which basically means no, you don't want it be a class member.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, that's the only way to implement the stream operator - outside the class.

You need to declare the method as `friend`.

That's how it's done.

Comment: There's usually no need to declare the function as a `friend`; anything you output is part of the public interface of the class.  (It's often appropriate to declare it as a friend in a template, in order to use the Barton and Nackman trick, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: This is seriously _not_ the only way to implement it. I've seen and implemented most stream operators without binding them as `friend`. Only were necessary, `friend` should be used.

Comment: @phresnel I tend to use the `print` method a lot, with class templates.  Not to gain access, but to be able to define the function within the class.

Comment: In his case, the member is private, so friendship is required. It's much simpler than adding getters just to be used by the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make it a non member (as the first parameter is not your class).

But you can write it inside your class definition (as a friend):

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    // Have a nice friend.
    // This tightly binds this operator to the class.
    // But that is not a problem as in reality it is already tightly bound.
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, TestClass const& data)
    {
        return os << "I'm in the class, msg=" << data.msg << endl;
    }

private:
    string msg;
};
```

I see nothing wrong with making this a friend.