# Where to put overload<< code?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the stream operator <<, for a class Foo which has already a  `toString()` function returning a string,  with the following code:

```
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &flux, Foo const& foo )
{
    flux <<  foo.toString(); 
    return flux;
}
```

In order to use it in a `main.cpp`file

My question is: Where to put that piece of code?

- If I place it in the `main.cpp`, before its usage, it works well, but i may want to use it in other files.
- If I place it in `foo.cpp`, I get a 'no such function' error:

  ```
  src/main.cpp:77: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << foo’
  ```

  which make sense since the code is not included to the `main.cpp` file
- If I place it in the `foo.h`class header, outside class declaration, I get a 'multiple definition' error:

  ```
  foo.o: In function `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Foo const&)':
  foo.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Matrix const&)'
  bar.o:bar.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
  ```

  The `foo.h` header is indeed included in different classes/files, but there is a ifdef guard, so I don't understand this.

So How should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple options:

#### Declare it in the header, after `Foo`, and define it in `Foo.cpp`.

```
//foo.h
class Foo
{};
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &s, Foo const& foo );

//foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &s, Foo const& foo )
{
    return s;
}
```

#### Define it as a `friend` inside the class definition.

```
//Foo.h
class Foo
{
   friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &s, Foo const& foo )
   {
      return s;
   }
};
```

#### Define it in the header, outside the class definition, and mark it as `inline` to prevent the multiple definition.

```
//Foo.h
class Foo
{
};

inline std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &s, Foo const& foo )
{
   return s;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the prototype of the overload by the class declaration, the implementation thereof at the `Foo` implementation (or if you want it `inline`, put it at the `Foo` declaration).

So either:

```
// foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H_ASDSADKJSLADJL
#define FOO_H_ASDSADKJSLADJL
class Foo {
};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &, Foo const &);
#endif // FOO_H_ASDSADKJSLADJL
```

---

```
// foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"
....
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, Foo const &) {
    ....
    return os;
}
```

or

```
#ifndef FOO_H_ASDSADKJSLADJL
#define FOO_H_ASDSADKJSLADJL
class Foo {
};
inline std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, Foo const &) {
    ....
    return os;
}
#endif // FOO_H_ASDSADKJSLADJL
```

Your error of the compiler not finding it was the lack of a prototype of your overload.

Comment: I think the downvote came because your first answer had 'nineteenmorecharacters' in it.

Comment: Nope, it's still not correct. You have an unmatched ´#endif` in foo.cpp. Additionally, the formulation "put it nearby Foo" is crap.

Comment: @Xymostech: I admit that was unusual, but I don't think that invalidates the answer that was contained.

Comment: @phresnel I'm not the one that downvoted, I was just writing up my answer when I saw it happen. Your edit came about 15 seconds later, but the damage had been done.

Comment: @Stefan: `You have an unmatched ´#endif` in foo.cpp`: Yeah right, but a downvote would be better than a comment? Further: The original content is gone now; I still disagree it is crap, because it is, imho, a good rule of thumb for beginners. It can be formulated better, but likewise can your commentary about it being "crap".

Comment: @phresnel: Well it's way better now. But what do you intend by "put it nearby Foo"? That's confusing for beginners. Just remove it and your answer is fine. I surely would remove that downvote ;-)

Comment: +1 because it's correct, but you have to admit the original "Put it nearby Foo" was pretty much useless. FGITW only works if the initial answer is correct & complete. :P Trust me, I know.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore @Stefan: Maybe my intention was not clear. The phrase `put it nearby Foo` was in contrast to the OP's `If I place it in the main.cpp, before its usage, it works well,`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It is usually not my style to be FGITW (see also my previous comment), sometimes though, a laconic real answer is my intention, and after that I realise it needs more refinement. Remember our discussion? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Put the declaration in the header file, and the definition in the cpp file.

That is, put

```
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &flux, Foo const& foo );
```

in your header file, and put

```
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &flux, Foo const& foo )
{
    flux <<  foo.toString(); 
    return flux;
}
```

in your cpp file.

This way, you can include the header file wherever you want, and things can use the function, but it will only be defined once, so you won't get the `multiple definitions` error.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I don't know why I didn't thought of this.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it in the header, where you declare `Foo`, define it in the source, where you define `Foo` methods.

Answer (score 0):

As ususal with C and C++, you should

1. put the actual code into the appropriate `.c` / `.cpp` file - here I would recommend `foo.cpp`
2. put a **predeclaration** into the appropriate `.h`/`.hpp` header file, with an appropriate `#ifdef` guard for everything that is used from outside the main c/cpp file.

In some situations, you can use a `#define` macro, or an `inline` function. This should then be done in the header; there shouldn't be a multiple declaration error because of the inlining.

**Technically** you can do a lot of things. I recommend sticking to the **best practise** of defining the API in the header file, and putting the implementation into the code file. This is most extensible. The `inline` hack will work for this case, but if you at some later point decides to enhance the method and remove the inline, it will surprisingly break.

The header / code split is least likely to break.